# Webpack for React doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, linux, reactjs, webpack

I am just start React and have finished `codecademy` courses and several other on youtube. I decide to configure my local machine for react. I ve started with webpack & webpack-dev-server. And here I get mistake.
[Here is mistake screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty8tU.png)

[Also Here is my files tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etqR9.png)

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'
    ],
    output: {
           path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
           filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loader: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React ToDos App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And index.js:

```
let message = 'Hello from entry message';

console.log(message);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have Express static folder setup in your `index.js` file?

Comment: What do you mean ? I am still not so progressive.

Comment: [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), also you need to specify output to your public folder.

Comment: Why I need public folder ?

Comment: That's where scripts and styles go. If you don't want to configure it from scratch, you can use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) instead.

Comment: I have change my code in output. See it. Why I need Express static folder if I use webpack and write in react ?

Comment: Ok, I have forgotten to ask this question: Do you use node as server?

Comment: I have any server yet, but I am planning to use it when will handle with react.

Comment: Yes, but are you using node/express server right now?

Comment: Nope. Do I extremely need to do it right now?

Comment: It's extremely recommended to use node/express alongside webpack and react. There are some preconfigured boilerplates available, so you can start typing in React, like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which uses Babel, Webpack and Node server.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it, but I wanna do it with typing configuration. I am very thankful for these advices. I wanna ask you about node/express. May be you know some tutorials how to start with node/express for webpack&react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues in your code:

1. The name of js bundle should be the same in html and in webpack – you use `ready.js` in webpack config and `bundle.js` in your html.
2. On your screenshot you have a typo and name of webpack config is `webpack.congig.js`, but it should be `webpack.config.js` (that is used by default by webpack-dev-server)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second is the answer. Who read this, be careful in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `webpack` config you're setting the output `filename` as `ready.js` and in your HTML your are looking for `bundle.js`. This is the reason for the error. Give a same name in both the places.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React ToDos App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="ready.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only if I in console type webpack, it return 'Output filename not configured'.

Comment: If I type webpack-dev-server it is work but not in chrome. I chrome it return about bundle.js not found.

Comment: Fix your webpack config first!